# Ktor-Exposed database migration

Tags: kotlin, ktor, kotlin-exposed

**Question**:

How to maintain database migration history using Exposed framework's `SchemaUtils`?

**Background:**

Recently, we have started evaluating API development using Ktor with Exposed.
and noticed that exposed offers database migration feature built-in using `SchemaUtils`.

```
transaction(database) {
            SchemaUtils.create(Articles)
        }
```

I was able to find out the basic documentation from [here](https://ktor.io/docs/interactive-website-add-persistence.html#create_table) but I could not find how answers to following?

- How to execute migration for altering table structure?
- How to manage migration history similar to other what RoR or liquibase does?

  - RoR manages migration history in database table for maintenance purpose
  - liquibase provides a similar feature

The only thing, I could confirm are the console logs by expose indicating which tables are created.

**Additional Details:**

- Ktor version : 2.3.7
- Kotlin version : 2.3.7
- Exposed version : 0.45.0

Any guidance is much appreciated.

Comment: There is no such functionality in Exposed, but a good starting point would be calling the `SchemaUtils.statementsRequiredToActualizeScheme` method to generate the statements for actualizing the existing tables. Those statements can be fed to a tool (like Flyway) that maintains database migration history.

Comment: @AlekseiTirman Thank you for the comment, I tried looking for statementsRequiredToActualizeScheme method but could not find any reference. Could you please share some reference doc or sample code for the same?
Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no documentation apart from the API docs of the method. You can call the `SchemaUtils.statementsRequiredToActualizeScheme()` method to obtain the list of queries that must be executed to migrate.